# Deleting A Session When Client Is No Longer Present

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'll give a simplified explanation of what I'm aiming to do.

Two individuals have established PHP sessions on a webpage.  One person leaves the page and the other person is still present.  After 60 seconds, the person who left needs their entire session terminated (like a timeout).

What I've been doing is having everyone logged into the page act as a ping timer through AJAX requests and the ping timer waits until the disconnected person's last ping is older than 60 seconds.  It can then eliminate data files associated with the person who logged out, but I can't figure out how to delete the whole session without first switching the current session to the session to be deleted, deleting it, and then switching back somehow.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  Or an alternative that is more efficient and less bandwidth-heavy than a series of AJAX requests?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've got millions of users leaving stale session files lying around, then don't bother with this.

If you need a 60 second time out, then set PHP's session max_lifetime to be 60 seconds, and set the session garbage collector to run fairly frequently.

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60); // 60 second lifetime
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session_gc.divisor', 100);   // garbage collector has 1% chance of running
```

with that, the collector will be run automatically on about 1%  (1/100) of the incoming hits, and it will delete any session files which have not been used in at least 60 seconds.

Comment: that is clever, good find! I'll implement that in my own websites

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, when you leave a website, your session is automatically destroyed by the garbage collector, so this seems like something you shouldn't be worried about.